# Spring Quickstart Guide generated demo fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Am new to Spring. Followed directions on https://spring.io/quickstart. On [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) page, I left "Gradle - Groovy" (default) as project, "3.1.1" (default) as Spring Boot, "17" (default) as Java, and added "Spring Web" as dependencies. I clicked on "Generate" to get the 70 KB `demo.zip` file. I expanded and moved the `demo` folder to my eclipse (2021-12) workspace, created a Java project using the same name "demo" (as existing project). I modified the `DemoApplication.java` file per step 2 on the [Quickstart](https://spring.io/quickstart) page. Ran `./gradlew bootRun` in console (macOS) per step 3. And I got a build failure. The first item is:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1.
```

I also noticed that the `demo.zip` file does not contain any `springframework` library. None of the `springframework.boot` or `springframework.web` imports could be resolved in eclipse IDE.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The problem was due to the environment variable `$JAVA_HOME` pointing to a JRE instead of a JDK. The JRE has no `javac`.